Why is Task.apS executing the tasks in parallel?
Someone told me that apS for Task and TaskEither is triggering them in parallel. I have checked for real that it is like that, but I don't know if it is just an implementation detail, or if it comes from the very essence of the conceptual definition.Can I rely on it?
